# why does RAM explode when retrieving documents from mongodb when the collection itself is small?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with 3.9 million documents with an average size of the document being 1.5 KB. The collection takes 5.7 GB of the disk space on the server. I'm trying to collect all the documents in a python script and the memory reaches to 60GB freezing the server (linux).

Here is what I'm doing

```
collec = mongo_db['my_collec']
records = []
crsr = collec.find()

for r in crsr:
    record.append(r)
```

I'd like to understand why does this process takes up so much memory when the data itself shouldn't take more than ~6GB. Each document contains ~100 fields.

Comment: You cannot just naively assume that the memory requirements to store something on disk are the same as materializing an entirely different representation in-memory

Comment: There is overhead involved.  Those strings in Mongo will be expanded to dictionaries.  You'll have a list with 4 million dictionaries, each of which has overhead.  You will need to rethink your strategy.  The Mongo cursor is smart about "chunking" the data a bit at a time.

Comment: So, you can think of MongoDB as just a key-value store of JSON. If we just wanted to store the bytes, `b'{"a":[1,2,3]}'` on disk, that would require about 13 bytes. If we want to materialize a Python dictionary with a list value, it takes *significantly more*. Just the dict will require 232 bytes, the list an additional 120. That's ignoring the string and ints in Python, which are very heavy-weight (although in this case they would all be cached)

Comment: Got it. I need to break my processes in parts then since I cannot process all the data at once.

Comment: A reason is likely to be because of the array field `records = []`. If you are storing all the documents from the `find` query (and it is so), and the array is stored in memory (RAM).

Comment: Also, the `find` method returns a [cursor](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor) - this has option called `batch_size` which allows optimize the read performance. Also, for large collections, with MongoDB v4.4 you can also specify the `allow_disk_use` option.

Comment: The default storage engine in mongodb wiredTiger is using by default snappy compression mechanism which can provide up to 70-80% compression ratio. So you will always have difference in what is stored on disk and what is loaded in memory. You can see the differeces easy with db.collection.stats(1024*1024*1024).size and db.collection.stats(1024*1024*1024).storageSIze , if you use zlib the difference will be even bigger ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High-level languages like Python have very high memory overhead, especially for small objects.

I don't know exact sizes, but it is very possible that a dictionary `{a: 1}`, which you might think "should" occupy, maybe, less than 10 bytes, actually needs 100 or 200 bytes of storage.

When you have nested data structures this overhead is present at each level.

To process bulk data in languages like Python, you need to:

- Process in small batches, e.g. 1000 documents at a time, or
- Utilize special data structures that have efficient in-memory layouts (scientific libraries in particular implement them, because they *must* process large quantities of data).